# Contact form is not working using PHP, I want to just send mail using PHP form

Tags: php, html, email

I have PHP email form, I want to sent an email using PHP form, but this is not working.

HTML:-

```
<form action="mail_handler.php" method="post" name="form" class="form-box">
    <label for="name">Name</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required><br>
    <label for="email">Email ID</label><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required><br>
    <label for="phone">Phone</label><br>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" class="inp" placeholder="Enter Your Phone" required><br>
    <label for="message">Message</label><br>
    <textarea name="msg" class="msg-box" placeholder="Enter Your Message Here..." required></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="sub-btn">
</form>
```

PHP:-

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $name=$_POST['name'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $msg=$_POST['msg'];

        $to='123@gmail.com'; // Receiver Email ID, Replace with your email ID
        $subject='Form Submission';
        $message="Name :".$name."Phone :".$phone."Wrote the following :".$msg;
        $headers="From: ".$email;

        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo "<h1>Sent Successfully! Thank you, We will contact you shortly!</h1>";
        }
        else{
            echo "Something went wrong!";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer will be appreciated!

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: May be your smtp server is not setup or something, try to use `error_get_last();`

Comment: Not a PHP player, but Just raising a point that PHP's `mail` function is not that good and gives hard luck in sending emails or I say in receiving. I need to switch `PhpMailer`

Comment: What error you got from the server or localhost. Describe the occurred error some times message more than 70 letters you need to wrap it. because each line should be separated with an LF (\n) and Lines should not exceed 70 characters.
use the below code to wrap the message.
`$message = wordwrap($message,70);` will wrap the message.

Comment: I'm getting error 'Something went wrong!'

Comment: is this all your code ?? 
is it local or on server ?

Comment: its working fine now, ignore this question!

Answer (score 1):

From PHP manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

You are not using headers here. Use the below code

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set. I think you are missing this
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

// Additional headers . 
$headers[] = 'From:  <'.$email.'>'; 

// Mail it
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers))) //Multiple extra headers should be separated with a CRLF (\r\n).
{
   echo "<h1>Sent Successfully! Thank you, We will contact you shortly!</h1>";
}else{
  echo "Something went wrong!";
}
```

Comment: getting same error again 'Something went wrong!'

Comment: actually this is not working on localhost but working on server but there is new issue "now mail is coming in spam folder"

Comment: By default it will not work in localhost but it works in server. For localhost , you have to setup your localhost . See here for localhost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost or else use `phpmailer` for localhost

Comment: If you want to use `PHPMailer `, go through this link https://www.codexworld.com/how-to-send-email-from-localhost-in-php/

Comment: If it works accept this answer